# asp.net core authentication using firebase

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, firebase-authentication, bearer-token

I'm trying to create an asp.net core api that verifies the user Identity using firebase authentication, and store all his data in internal postgreSQL data base - including rules for authorization (such as Admin and other custom rules).

I Managed to verify the token using the firebase nuget package:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(
           Configuration.GetConnectionString("DeafultConnectionString")));

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddFirebaseAuthentication(Configuration.GetSection("FirebaseAuth:issuer").Value,
            Configuration.GetSection("FirebaseAuth:audience").Value);

      //  services.AddIdentity<Auth.ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

and this works perfectly fine!
I'm trying to understand how I connect my database to store the user details - but I can't uderstand how it's done.
any help?